# Pandas complex GroupBy or Pivot with non numerical data

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a set of data that I'm trying to filter and group. For each unique ID, I want to get a count of unique users, IPs, and names, then list those things out.

I've used this line to filter the data down to what I want, and I think its working:

```
df = df[df.isin(df[df.duplicated(subset=['id'], keep=False)])]
```

The result looks something like this:

```
       id      user          ip             name
x123.blah       123     1.1.1.1         whatever
x123.blah       212     1.1.1.1         whatever
x123.blah       212     2.2.2.2         whatever
x123.blah       345     1.1.1.1   something_else
y321.blah       444     3.3.3.3              mom
y321.blah       555     3.3.3.3              mom
y321.blah       666     3.3.3.3              mom
```

Currently I'm having to output this as 2 separate files, one doing a groupby to get a count of unique values per name, and another is just the whole DF. I have to check both, which is not ideal.

```
df_g = df.groupby(['id','name']).user.nunique(dropna=False).reset_index()

       id             name     user
x123.blah         whatever        2
x123.blah   something_else        1
y321.blah              mom        3
```

What I want is this:

```
       id              name                  ip            user

x123.blah                 2                   2               3
                   whatever    1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2        123, 212
             something_else             1.1.1.1             345

y321.blah                 1                   1               3
                        mom             3.3.3.3   444, 555, 666
```

Is this something that can even be accomplished with GroupBy?  I messed around a bit with pivot tables but i got errors because of non numerical values

Comment: Is it important that this have a MultiIndex for the output? And is what you want for "ip" and "user" really a string of all values joined with strings, or a list?

Comment: IP and User can be a string or a list, it doesn't matter for my use case. I don't think that MultiIndex is important, the output is just being analyzed by a human so as long as it is readable it would be fine

Comment: @r1ty check my answer it works very well with my code upvote and tick if you find relavant.